# REST Client step in Pentaho DI (Kettle) says I do not have permission to API

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I am using version 5.1 of Pentaho DI (Kettle) and am having an issue with the "Rest Client" step.  The step executes properly and successfully, but the result says I do not have permission to use the API.  I have confirmed in another tool that I **do** have permission.  I have entered my login information on the Authentication tab and have built my URL to include my token.

What am I missing?

ADDITIONAL INFO: I am having the same issue with the "HTTP Post" step.  The status being returned from the API is 403.

Answer (score 1):

403 is "Forbidden". Check that you have the correct credentials to access the webservice. The request went through and the server rejected sending the response because username/password are not correct or otherwise the user does not have permissions for that request. Can you see the response correctly in a browser when you enter EXACTLY the same credentials? To avoid active browser sessions masking the real issue I'd test it on incognito/private browsing mode on the browser.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have confirmed that I DO have permission in a java call.  I think this may have something to do with how Pentaho is formatting the request.

Comment: try sending the Kettle request to a port on your local system that you listen to and just dump whatever arrives. Do the same with the call that is working. There have to be differences, one of the differences is the cause you're looking for. Once you get that, either there's a checkbox you can check/uncheck on PDI, or there may be a limitation on PDI.